# Cannot push data from a local instance of postgresql to heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I have followed various links including Herokus documentation here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#using-the-cli

I am using the command:
pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h $DB_LOCAL_URL -U $DB_LOCAL_USER ${DB_LOCAL_DATABASE} > my_database.dmp
to create the database. It creates the dump okay. Put I cannot figure out how to push it:

I tried:
heroku pg:push my_database.dmp  <my_heroku_databaseurl> --app myapp
Where <my_heroku_databaseurl> is the value of heroku config -a myapp command, which gives

```
=== myapp Config Vars
DATABASE_URL:my_heroku_databaseurl>
```

This gives an error:
Unknown database: postgres:.......
If I try
heroku pg:push my_database.dmp <heroku_database_name>  --app myapp
Unknown database: <heroku_database_name> Valid options are: DATABASE_URL

I tried every variation without success, dropping username, database name etc.

The Heroku documentation simply says:
heroku pg:push mylocaldb HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAGENTA --app sushi
But what exactly is HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAGENTA in this instance?

The other example given is:

```
# push mylocaldb into a Heroku DB named postgresql-swimmingly-100
$ heroku pg:push mylocaldb postgresql-swimmingly-100
```

but what from the perspective of my local machine is postgresql-swimmingly-100?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAGENTA is a dummy word just replace it with DATABASE_URL